# difficulty in updating csv file

Tags: python, django

I tried to update the CSV file with a description column.  I tried to add an update to the model by adding `description = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='SOME STRING')` like this:

```
wine = models.ForeignKey(Wine)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    rating = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING_CHOICES)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='SOME STRING')
```

When I run migrate for this change I get the following error:

```
c:\Users\Amira Joshi\Desktop\winerama>python manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'reviews':
  reviews\migrations\0002_review_description.py
    - Add field description to review
```

How can I solve it?  Please help!

Comment: Can you please show the entire model and the Error? Because based on what you're showing it looks like Django has created a new migration file under your `reviews` app. Try running `python manage.py migrate` to run the new migrations.

Comment: Grammar and more correct English translation

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error:

```
c:\Users\Amira Joshi\Desktop\winerama>python manage.py makemigrations 
Migrations for 'reviews':   reviews\migrations\0002_review_description.py
    - Add field description to review
```

With this django says that the migration file is created, now you must apply the migration by running this command:

```
python manage.py migrate
```